# Sync directory with a repository hosted on github

Tags: git, github, synchronization, git-merge

We have an application that clients install on their servers. They can obtain it in 2 ways: by downloading an archive from the website and by cloning the application from a github based repository.

Recently we added a module that syncs with the repository and provides patching functionality. It works fine with cloned instances of the system. Is it possible to sync/merge directory (containing downloaded from the website content) with the repository on github? What is the best way to do so? We can assume that Git is installed on the client's server, directory structure has no significant changes and all the merge conflicts will be solved manually by the user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can initiating a repo, adding the remote to it and then merging the remote repo be considered an option? As I understand, the user needs to pull in the remote changes and not lose their data?

Comment: Yes, the data should not be lost. Will just adding a remote be enough? Won't there be any conflicts with HEAD ref? Client needs to be able to run 'checkout', 'status', 'log', 'add', 'commit', 'rm', 'remote', 'fetch', 'merge', 'reset', make pull requests, list available patches and install them.

Comment: I tried something like this, I'm not sure I understood correctly what you meant, but I tried :) http://showterm.io/cfa56732870440c08f3bd#fast